# Get Page Name/ID of Content Element in Backend Edit View

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid-styled-content

I'm new to Typo3.

Inside the Configuration section of my own Content element I need the ID or name of the Content element's page. How would you implement that?

I already tried to use [`flux:field.input`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Pipe/ControllerViewHelper.html) but I dont know what to do with typoscript.

Comment: Hey, can you post a screenshot in which view you try to get the information? And for what you need this information?

Comment: In each content element you have the field `pid` (parent Id) which normaly identifies the page the record belongs to.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler A customer wanted a label to have a different name if the item was in a specific folder. I ended up using `{f:if(condition: '{record.pid} == 204', then: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`record.pid`](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/308#issuecomment-23415397) was the thing I was looking for!

```html
<f:debug>{record}</f:debug>
```